# is laravel 5.4 running migrations from vendor folders now?

Tags: laravel

I have installed some packages that have migrations in their vendor folders, previously one of the packages I used published these migrations to migrations folder by running:

php artisan vendor:publish

Now I found alteast 2 packages that no longer published migrations when running this command, so I went into vendor folder and grabbed migration file and manually moved it and when I run

composer dump-autoload I got a warrning message from it that said: Warning:

> Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateRevisionsTable" was found in both "$baseDir . '/database/migrations/2013_04_09_062329_create_revisions_table.php" and "C:\xampp\htdocs\example\vendor/venturecraft/revisionable/src/migrations\2013_04_09_062329_create_revisions_table.php", the first will be used.

why is this happening? Has something changed in 5.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since version 5.4 Laravel supports loading migrations from any directory.

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/migrations');
```

Which could be used by a service provider of any package.

Comment: I am developing my custom package using this : https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-package-laravel/ but i am not able to run the migration. it seems the execution is coming to the above line but no table is being created.

Comment: @AmitShah make sure you have the correct path into the `loadMigrationsFrom()` method and the migration file is inside. This will probably not throw an error on a not found path or empty folder.

Comment: thanks it was my mistake about the wrong relative path.